# How to query an array of values with priority in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an array of key value pairs, i.e, each array contains an id, email_id and name.
How do I make a query in elastic search so that each array will match only a single item and in priority of id, email and then name i.e, if we found a match from id, then that value is returned. If no match found for the id, then we look for email_id followed by name.
Example input:

```
[
    {id: 1, email_id: "xyz@abc", name: "xyz"},
    {id: 2, email_id: "xxy@abc", name: "xxy"}
]
```

In example array contains only 2 items, so maximum of 2 results should be retrieved.
How can I write this query ?

I couldn't think of any way to tackle in a single query

Answer (score 0):

a single query with a `function_score` to prioritize matching:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "id": [1, 2]
              }
            },
            {
              "terms": {
                "email_id": ["xyz@abc", "xxy@abc"]
              }
            },
            {
              "terms": {
                "name": ["xyz", "xxy"]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "terms": {
              "id": [1, 2]
            }
          },
          "weight": 3
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "terms": {
              "email_id": ["xyz@abc", "xxy@abc"]
            }
          },
          "weight": 2
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "terms": {
              "name": ["xyz", "xxy"]
            }
          },
          "weight": 1
        }
      ],
      "score_mode": "max",
      "boost_mode": "replace"
    }
  }
}
```